# copy and rename files

Tags: bash, copy, cp, mv

Here are my access logs those I want to backup.

```
/var/log/httpd/access_log
/var/log/httpd/access_log.1
/var/log/httpd/access_log.2
/var/log/httpd/access_log.3 
...
```

I want to copy all these files but with different name:

The following does work as expected, but is it possible to write a single command assuming there will be a lot of files to copy?

```
cp /var/log/httpd/access_log /home/shantanu/access_log.bak
cp /var/log/httpd/access_log.1 /home/shantanu/access_log.1.bak
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

```
for f in /var/log/httpd/access_log*; do cp $f /home/shantanu/$(basename $f).bak; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls /var/log/httpd/access_log* | xargs -I% cp % %.bak
mv /var/log/httpd/*.bak /to/somewhere
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the `mv` command in xargs? If /var/log and /to/somewhere are on different volumes, you're writing the file twice.

Comment: because, the `%` expanded as full path name, so mv % /somewhere/%.bak will expand as mv /var/log/access.log /somewhere/var/log/access.log.bak. Handling with basename and etc - this is much easier...

Answer (score 0):

```
find access_log* -type f -execdir mv {} {}.bak \;
```